# Using correct number in calculation c#

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, primes, greatest-common-divisor

A user enters two prime numbers which are then multiplied together, and another calculation of (a-1) * (b-1) is completed (a and b being the prime numbers entered).  a function to checks the numbers entered, if the numbers are NOT prime, the user will be asked to re-enter the numbers. However, when I test this, I've noticed that if the user inputs a number which ISN'T prime, and then re-enters a prime number, the calculations are based on the number which ISN'T prime. E.g. if the user enters 2 and 4, since 4 isn't prime they are asked to enter another number, e.g 3, the calculations will be based on the numbers 2 and 4.

How can I correct this so it takes the valid prime number and not the invalid number originally entered?

```
namespace example
{
class Program
{
    class Co_P
    {
            
        static void coprime(ref int c, int calculation)
        {

            if (gcd(c, calculation) == 1)
                Console.WriteLine("it's Co-Prime");

            else
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it isn't Co-Prime");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Co-Prime");
                    c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    coprime(ref c, calculation);
                } while (gcd(c, calculation) != 1);
        }

        static int Prime_a(int a) //check a is prime

        {
            if (a <= 1) return 0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= a / 2; i++)
            {
                if (a % i == 0)
                {
                    return 0; //not prime
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }

        static void result(int a) //outputs if a is prime/or not 
        {

            if (Prime_a(a) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a + " is a prime number");
            }

            else do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + " isn't prime number");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please make sure you enter a prime number");
                    a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                } while (Prime_a(a) == 0);
        }

        static int Prime_b(int b)

        {
            if (b <= 1) return 0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= b / 2; i++)
            {
                if (b % i == 0)
                {
                    return 0;  
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }

        static void resultb(int b) 
        {
            int result = Prime_b(b);

            if (Prime_b(b) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b + " is a prime number");
            }

            else do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(b + " is not a prime number");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please make sure you enter a prime number");
                    b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                } while (Prime_b(b) == 0);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a prime number for a");
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            result(a);
            Console.WriteLine();

           int b;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a prime number for b");
            b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            resultb(b);
            Console.WriteLine();

           int total = a * b; 
           Console.WriteLine("The total of the prime numbers is = " + total);

            int calculation = (a - 1) * (b - 1); //calculation 
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The result = " + calculation);
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static void resultb(int b)` <- this `b` is local to the scope of the method. You can change it, but the change won't be reflected in the calling scope. Look up "pass by value".

Comment: You may want to read about scopes of variables. If you'd step through the program with the debugger you will find that in case of non-prime input the variable in the scope of `result()` or `resultb()` is set to the new input not the variable in the scope of `Main()`. From a design perspective it's also weird to have the input be read in two (three) places. Either have a method that reads the input and returns it to `Main()` or handle the input completely in `Main()`.

Comment: Then you don't need both, `Prime_a()` and `Prime_b()` they're doing exactly the same thing. Same goes for `result()` and `result_b()`.

Comment: And for `Prime_a()` (or `Prime_b()`) you should consider to return a `bool` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Unrelated: Please don't tag-spam. Neither "primes" nor "gcd" are part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int b;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a prime number for b");
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        resultb(b);
        Console.WriteLine();
```

In line `resultb(b);` you are passing `int` to method `resultb`. `int` is a **value type**, or in other words, passing `int` to a method means passing its value to a method, where copy of that value is created. In this case a copy of `b` is created in method `resultb`. Every further change on `b` inside method `resultb` is made on copy and original stays the same.

In `resultb` method pass parameter **by reference** by adding `ref` keyword. Instead

```
static void resultb(int b)
{
    // code
}
```

method will look like this

```
static void resultb(ref int b)
{
    // code
}
```

You will call the method this way

```
resultb(ref b);
```

Here's the portion of code.

```
    int b;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a prime number for b");
    b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    resultb(ref b);
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Now every change on passed `b` inside method `resultb` will reflect on the original.

You should do the same for method `result(int a)`.

Comment: Why not just return an int? `out` params do have their place. This is not a good fit, however.

Comment: @Fildor This way is more elegant.

Comment: @Fildor I've corrected the answer using the `ref` keyword. @Rubikted I've added the explanation. You only need to change the signature of method `resultb`.

Answer (score 3):

You should extend `result` and `resultb` function so it returns new prompted valid number

```cs
static int result(int a) {
  var result = Prime_a(a);
  if (result != 0)
  ...code...
  return result
}
```

Also don't forget to reassign those values

```cs
  ...code...
  a = result(a);
  ...code...
  b = resultb(b);
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I am struggling. Your answer is not wrong. But is it really "enough"? We cannot give him a beginner's tutorial .... argh I feel so bad.

Comment: the line static in result (int a), the word result is highlighted red, with the error "Program.Co_Prime.result(int)': not all code paths return a value
?

Comment: That means value is returned inside condition but not outside or vice versa